# SQL Server : select distinct data with transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+------+----------+
|   make    |    model    |     variant     | year |  price   |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+------+----------+
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LS            | 2018 |  1000000 |
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LS            | 2017 |  2000000 |
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LS            | 2016 |  3000000 |
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LSTRENDY      | 2018 |  4000000 |
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LSTRENDY      | 2017 |  5000000 |
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LSTRENDY      | 2016 |  6000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVX        | 2018 |  7000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVX        | 2017 |  8000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVX        | 2016 |  9000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVX        | 2015 | 10000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVXLIMITED | 2018 | 11000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVXLIMITED | 2017 | 12000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVXLIMITED | 2016 | 13000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVXLIMITED | 2015 | 14000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVXLIMITED | 2014 | 15000000 |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVXLIMITED | 2013 | 16000000 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+------+----------+
```

I want to select data in below form

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   make    |    model    |     variant     |   2018   |   2017   |   2016   |   2015   |   2014   |   2013   |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LS            |  1000000 |  2000000 |  3000000 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| CHEVROLET | SPARK       | 08LSTRENDY      |  4000000 |  5000000 |  6000000 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVX        |  7000000 |  8000000 |  9000000 | 10000000 | NULL     | NULL     |
| TOYOTA    | LANDCRUISER | 10042DVXLIMITED | 11000000 | 12000000 | 13000000 | 14000000 | 15000000 | 16000000 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Could you please help me to write a query for this?

Comment: . . Do not post image only text format is fine.

Comment: Actually, I have to achieve this only using SQL script.

Comment: WEll - we'll help - but you need to **first show YOUR efforts** so far - what's your query so far? Where are you stuck??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select make, model, variant,
       sum(case when yr = 2018 then price else 0 end),
       sum(case when yr = 2017 then price else 0 end),
       sum(case when yr = 2016 then price else 0 end),
       sum(case when yr = 2015 then price else 0 end)
from table t
group by make, model, variant;
```

Comment: @nikhil . . . To get `NULL` values (as in the question), remove the `else 0` clause.